# Only retaining polygons that would intersect with a point but not taking point data

Tags: python, polygon, point, geopandas

I want to see if a polygon contains a point data of interest (in this case an observation of grain yield), but I really don't care about the point data (grain yield), I just want the polygons that would contain grain data if I did join them. When I spatial join them this works, but then I end up with a bunch of duplicate observations because there are often multiple points within a single polygon (e.g., data frame goes from 1300 to 3800 rows).

I got it to work in a very round-about way, but I'd like to know if there's a better method. What I've done so far:

```
#read in my two files
polygons = gpd.read_file('shapes.geojson')
points = gpd.read_file('points.geojson')

#sjoin left
points_in_polygons = gpd.sjoin(polygons, points, how='left')

#remove any polygons that have a null value for grain yield
points_in_polygons = points_in_polygons[points_in_polygons['yield'].notna()]

# consolidate them by the mean so I don't have excess observations
points_in_polygons.groupby(level=0).mean()
```

Answer (score 3):

If all you want are polygons that intersect with points, you can [drop duplicate](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html)s after the join, by specifying the polygon id field as the subset:

```
#read in my two files
polygons = gpd.read_file('shapes.geojson')
points = gpd.read_file('points.geojson')

#sjoin
points_in_polygons = gpd.sjoin(polygons, points, how='inner')
points_in_polygons.drop_duplicates(subset=['poly_id_field'])
```

This will give you a unique list of the polygons that intersect with points.